# How to setup net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle in a docker container

Tags: docker, jmeter

When using JMeter docker to do stress test, I need to set up **tcp_tw_recycle** to enable fast recycling TIME_WAIT sockets according to [this advice](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/linux-tuning-support-more-users-jmeter-load-tests-lakshmi-narayan/). But I encountered error message "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle: no such file or directory" when running the JMeter docker container.

```
docker run --privileged -i -v /e/JMeter:/JMeter -w /JMeter --rm --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1 vinsdocker/jmserver:latest  -n -t "/JMeter/TestNginx.jmx" -l "/JMeter/log/log.jtl" -e -o "/JMeter/output/"
```

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"write sysctl key net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle: open ?/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle: no such file or directory\"": unknown.
```

The base image of [this JMeter docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/vinsdocker/jmserver) is "openjdk:8-jre-slim".

Docker version:
**Docker version 19.03.8**, build afacb8b

I found the files in /sys/net/ipv4/ folder are different when running in different docker hosts.
In Docker Desktop for windows, I found **62** files starting with /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_*. But there're only **6** these kind of files in Docker for Linux in CentOS7. And **there isn't file named tcp_tw_recycle**.  Why are they different in different Docker hosts?

Execute `uname -a` in the container in Docker Desktop for windows(Wins10).

```
root@b8a08c3ea9ab:/# uname -a
Linux b8a08c3ea9ab 4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Execute `uname -a` in the container in Docker for Linux(CentOS7).

```
root@7d929239742c:/# uname -a
Linux 7d929239742c 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 15:27:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Links:

1. [Configure namespaced kernel parameters (sysctls) at runtime](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime)
2. [Enabling Unsafe Sysctls in kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/#enabling-unsafe-sysctls)